# Couchbase Why a simple query is slow on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have a simple query and it takes 240ms - 280ms to execute.

In my shell on my capella dashboard it takes 3ms.

config:

```
import {
  Bucket,
  Cluster,
  Collection,
  connect,
  GetResult,
  Scope,
} from 'couchbase';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';

export const cbdb = async () => {
  try {
    const cluster: Cluster = await connect('couchbases://cb.xxx.cloud.couchbase.com', {
      username: 'xxxx',
      password: 'xxxxx!',
          // Use the pre-configured profile below to avoid latency issues with your connection.
          configProfile: "wanDevelopment",
    });

    const bucket: Bucket = cluster.bucket('bucket');

    const scope: Scope = bucket.scope('scope');

    console.log('COUCHBASE CONNECTED');

    return scope;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('CBB')
    console.log(e);
    Sentry.captureException(`${e}`);
    return null;
  }
};
```

server.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import { cbdb } from './config/db';

const app = express();

const db = await cbdb();

app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    console.time("concatenation");
    const d = await db?.query('SELECT click FROM products WHERE META().id = $1', {
      parameters: ['products1']
    });
    console.timeEnd("concatenation");

    res.send('hello');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.send(e);
  }
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, async () => {
  console.log(`server started on port: ${port}`);
});
```

I take more then one execution and all query takes 240-280ms. What I am doing wrong ? I use capella trial. In my capella UI dashboard when I execute a query it takes 4ms

Comment: where is server.ts running? if it's running on your own machine, remember that you're making a request across the internet. ALSO, your SQL query can be replace with a key/value operation, which will be faster.

Comment: @MatthewGroves its running on my windows pc localhost, key value operation also takes 50ms where I have one key, if I fetch other things on internet it takes 2-10ms. So maybe he everytime creates a new connection but this is only supposition